# build.gradle cannot resolve symbol 'groovy.json.JsonSlurper'

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I can't resolve the groovy.json.JsonSlurper in the build.gradle file with Intellij, does anyone know how to fix it?

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



task sample() {
    doLast {
        sample();
    }
}

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def sample(){
    def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"a":"b"}')
    println(json);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missing the needed dependency.

Add `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.9` in `dependencies` section so ti will look like

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.9'
}
```

And then you can test with CLI as `gradle sample` or `./gradlew sample` and it will return `{a=b}`

Comment: Thank you! Solved it, I put it in the buildscript block and use it only with Gradle Script.